# SQL between not include all range of query (date)

Tags: sqlite, between

i have table with following structure:

[image]

And I'm trying to get grouped values between two dates, problem is that result does not contains row with date 2014-09-05.

**Here is the query:**

```
  SELECT substr(m.date, 1, 10) as my_date, COUNT(m.ID) AS 'NUMBER_OF_ALL_CALLS',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'DONE'
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_DONE',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NOT_INTERESTED' 
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NOT_INTERESTED',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialed_calls subq WHERE subq.call_result = 'NO_APPOINTMENT'
    AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) as 'RESULT_NO_APP'
    FROM dialed_calls m
    WHERE m.date BETWEEN "2014-09-02" AND "2014-09-05"
    GROUP BY my_date
```

How can i solve it to include rows for given range.

And also i would like to ask, how can i do that for missing days fxp:

```
WHERE m.date BETWEEN "2014-09-02" AND "2014-09-10"
```

Result returns date with zero values?

Many thanks for any help.

**Table structure:**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE dialed_calls(Id integer PRIMARY KEY,
'date' datetime,
'called_number' VARCHAR(45),
'call_result' VARCHAR(45),
'call_duration' INT,
'synced' BOOL);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(1,'2014-09-02 15:54:34+0200',
'800123456', 'NOT_INTERESTED', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(2,'2014-09-02 15:56:30+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(3,'2014-09-02 16:01:49+0200',
'800123456', 'DONE', 9, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(4,'2014-09-02 16:03:03+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 69, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(5,'2014-09-02 18:09:34+0200',
'800123456', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 3, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(6,'2014-09-02 18:54:02+0200',
'123456789', 'NO_APPOINTMENT', 89, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(7,'2014-09-02 18:55:25+0200',
'123456789', 'NOT_INTERESTED', 89, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(8,'2014-09-03 18:36:58+0200',
'123456789', 'DONE', 185, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(9,'2014-09-04 18:36:58+0200',
'123456789', 'DONE', 185, 0);
INSERT INTO dialed_calls VALUES(10,'2014-09-05 18:36:58+0200',
'123456789', 'DONE', 185, 0);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Multiple questions are too broad; ask the second question separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you just specify the date, the time defaults to 00:00:00.  If you add 23:59:59 to the end date, you should get the full range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

`x BETWEEN a AND B` is just a shorthand for `x >= a AND x <= b`.

If you do not want the `<=` operator for the second comparison, write it out manually, and change it so that you get any values before the next day:

```
... WHERE m.date >= '2014-09-02' AND m.date < '2014-09-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

to include rows for given range change

```
WHERE m.date BETWEEN "2014-09-02" AND "2014-09-05"
```

for

```
WHERE substr(m.date, 1, 10) BETWEEN '2014-09-02' AND '2014-09-05'
```